# deduplication problem with the genetic algorithm with Python

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I have a csv file with records of a biblio.

```
input:Records R={r1,r2,r3,.....rn},objectif function = {f}
Output  :   un  arrangement des clusters    des enregistrements R
```

**Coding of records**:

Each record  (is mapped by an integer i (see figure below):[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RyIZ.png][1]
Presentation of the solution

The solution is in the form of chromosome.

**Example:** For a set of records `R = {1,2,3,4,5}`, a solution as `{1,3,5}` is three clusters including representative of the first cluster is 1, the second representative is 2), the 3 rd  is 3.

**Calculation of distances :**
For each initialized chromosome, we calculate the distances of the unassigned recordings and assign them to the nearest cluster.
example:

```
R   ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
Ch1 = {2,4,5,6} is a chromosome representing a possible solution.
```

`1= {2},  2 = {4}, 3 = 5, 4 = {6}` are the clusters representing the solution.
The unassigned records are `=({1,3,7} = .`For each record we calculate the distance to each cluster, and the cluster having the minimum distance to the record will contain. Suppose `dist (1,  1) <dist (1,  2) <dist (1 ,3)) <dist (1 ,4)`, so the recording 1= 1 is added to the cluster 1. so `1 = {1,2}`.

function of similarity is Jaccard   distance    .

How can I do that with python .
Please I need help .